# Rails: most elegant way to render attributes of a record in a citation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a @story record with the following attributes:

- author
- author_title
- year
- source
- source_link

I'm rendering it in the view so it comes out like this:

> James Joyce (author), 1882, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Joyce)

I am hoping there is a less convoluted way to generate the DOM for the citation than this (which is imperfect, as I explain below):

```
<%= @story.author %><% if !@story.author_title.blank? %> (<%= @story.author_title %>)<% end %><% if !@story.year.blank? %>, <%= @story.year %><% end %><% if !@story.source_link.blank? %>, <%= link_to @story.source, @story.source_link, target: "_blank" %><% end %>
```

As none of the fields are mandatory, the if-field-not-nil-then-you-may-need-a-comma issue is what I suspect could be handled more elegantly. For example, if `author` is blank, then I don't want to display the author_title or the trailing comma.

Comment: If you really want to take this to the next level, consider creating Model Decorators. This is basically a class that wraps your model, in which you can create helper like methods that keep your Views clean. Check out Draper gem: https://github.com/drapergem/draper. It also makes sure you can easily unit test each of those functions, as it basically acts as a model.

Comment: If this gem is overkill, just create a model method for this... I personally dislike using helper methods for very specific tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code

create a two helper method

```
def author_story(author)
   [@story.author_title, @story.year].compact.join(',')
end

def author_link
  link_to(@story.source_link, text: 'testing')
end
```

and in view

```
<% if @story.author.present? %>
  <div>
     <span>
        <%= author_story(@story) %> 
     </span>
     <span>
        <%= author_link(@story) %>
     </span>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: can anyone please explain what is wrong in these. Because someone downvoted the answer

Comment: Thanks. I had the feeling compact and join would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

See my comments, Decorators is the way to go. You'll learn to love it and never go back.

If you think it is too much overhead for only a one-time simple task... then create a model method for this:

```
class Story < ApplicationRecord

  .... #other stuff

  def author_with_title_and_year
    "#{author} #{author_title}, #{year}".squish
  end

end
```

And add the link manually behind it:

```
<p><%= @story.author_with_title_and_year %> <%= link_to source, source_link %></p>
```